# Chrome extension get response after pageload in specific url list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest

I don't know if what I am looking for is possible, I want JS Chrome extension solution to get response after pageload in specific url like this picture.

[my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75z5Z.png)

Note: my webpage url is "*www.exmaple.com*"

I want response from "*[www.exmaple.com/get_ft_v2?userid=91642151*"](http://www.exmaple.com/get_ft_v2?userid=91642151*%22)

Comment: you want to make an extension or looking for a ready extension in store ?

Comment: So you want to get a response whenever you visit a specific URL like "www.stackoverflow.com" for example?

Comment: I'm developing extension but i dont know how to get response in specific url    my background.js  like this   chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
});